# Retro Tag for Vintage/Obsolete Apple Tech?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just putting this out there for opinions.

Would having a “Retro” tag be beneficial?

I am thinking this could cover everything older than, say 15 years old (i.e. White Unibody MacBook) and include all platforms like PPC, Intel, and even MOS (6502).

I see an opportunity to attract more engagement from the Retro community where questions/answers could be easily categorized and even have an RSS feed (automatically generated like with other filers).

Maybe a “site within a site” of sorts?

It wouldn’t be in addition to the existing tag qualifiers, but more of a catch all.

Comment: What would you see as a benefit of a rather broad tag covering vastly different hardware platforms, architectures and OS versions?

Comment: I added some context @nohillside

Comment: Interesting idea. How do you see this working in relation to Apple's use of the terms *Vintage* and *Obsolete* ? We'd probably need to ensure there's no confusion between *Retro* and those terms. Apple uses 5, 7 and 10 years for various definitions (see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624)).

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a good idea. The only thing is that there are very few questions covering this. This tag won't be used very often and I therefore don't really see the usefulness of it. Do you think this could be used more often by broadening it in a way (I have no idea how but-)?

Comment: That’s an excellent point @Monomeeth.  I “threw out” the 15 year time frame as a starting point.  I would envision this being past what Apple officially designates as [obsolete](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624).  Even though it’s obsolete, it’s still somewhat current a 2012 iMac, for example, can run Catalina and still be somewhat current today but becomes less so every year forward.

Comment: From SE's perspective, this looks like a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/?_ga=2.217216086.1171987271.1683128311-1119606515.1653407126) which is usually discouraged.

Comment: As for "*to attract more engagement from the Retro community where questions/answers could be easily categorized and even have an RSS feed (automatically generated like with other filers)*", in addition to the personal Tag Watch list, Stack Exchange actually has [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/416254/for-android-enthusiasts) supporting multiple tags that can be shared to and subscribed by anyone using RSS Feed.

Comment: Ask Different has been around for a while, and it's only getting older. When the site opened, someone may have had a question about a relatively-modern PPC Mac. Would that question get a retro tag added in 2023?

Comment: I don’t see why not @Wowfunhappy.  There’s definitely a community out there that run these vintage machined. I have two PPC Mac Pros and and a white 2007 MB that I am working on getting to run FreeBSD (white MB is mostly done) and the native OSX. Having a tag will allow creation of a feed/filter that could be perused at leisure

Comment: Remember there's also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ so a question can be migrated easily enough.  The demarc point between the two needs to be defined, and perhaps shouldn't be a moving target like "is currently sold" or "is supported by apple"   Perhaps "pre/post original imac"  ?

Comment: @Allan "I don't see why not" Well, the tricky thing is there's two ways to interpret these questions. One is to give a literal answer: this is how you'd do it on Leopard on a G4 Tower. The other is to give an "updated" answer:—this is how you'd do it today on modern software and hardware—and downvote any old answers for being "outdated". Irrespective of the tag, this is actually a bit of a problem, because there are significant advantages to both approaches, but they directly conflict with each other.